Restore from database snapshot
When I do a restore of a database from a database_snapshot on a filestream enabled database, I am getting the error:

The database cannot be reverted because FILESTREAM BLOBs are present.

Is it just not possible to do a restore from snapshot or do I have to specify something extra in the restore command?

From the docs:

FILESTREAM filegroups are not supported by database snapshots. If FILESTREAM filegroups exist in a source database, they are marked as offline in its database snapshots, and the database snapshots cannot be used for reverting the database.

! Note
A SELECT statement that is executed on a database snapshot must not specify a FILESTREAM column; otherwise, the following error message will be returned: Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.


So no it's not possible to revert using it. You might try setting that filegroup to read-only, as then it doesn't need to be reverted, but that probably also doesn't work (and obviously you couldn't modify the blobs).

thx for the quick answer
